# How to select only 3 records from multiple records in column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have table with 3 Columns (ID, CARDNO, CONTACTNO)

Each cardno have multiple contactno

```
ID    CARDNO          CONTACTNO
1     1234567895412   32225465987
2     1234567895412   65554789654
3     1234567895412   24445698741
4     1234567895412   24445698745
5     1234567895412   45556987123
```

I want only select 3 random contactno against 1 card

Comment: Do you really want random or just arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have several options, but I think that the easiest one is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM contact_data  -- your table name
 ORDER BY dbms_random.random
 FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT ID, CARDNO, CONTACTNO FROM
(SELECT ID, CARDNO, CONTACTNO, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CARDNO ORDER BY 1) AS RN
FROM YOUR_TABLE)
WHERE RN <= 3;
```

If you really need randomness then you can replace `ORDER BY 1` with `ORDER BY dbms_random.value(0,1)` in the `OVER` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: This is working. Now I am trying to join 2 more tables with this table. Can you help me?

Comment: Please share the details. sample data expected output and table details

Answer (score 0):

May be you can just try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CARDNO = '1234567895412' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

replace TABLE with your table name,

Answer (score 0):

If you really want *random* then use `row_number()` with a `dbms_random` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cardno order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Colloquially, though, people often use "random" but not in the technical sense.  If that is the case, you can replace the `order by` with whatever makes sense -- including dropping it altogether.